# Does economy class on JAL have power points?

Tags: air-travel, power, seating, jal

Flying on (Japanese Airlines) JAL this weekend (on a 787), but am wondering how I can find out what facilities USB, power points etc) that the seats have?

I would put my specific flight number here but I would assume there's a more generic way of finding this out, so hoping for an answer that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seatguru.com lists if AC power is available on the aircraft and in which seats.  Just enter your flight details and it will display the aircraft type currently scheduled for your flight.

Comment: In the US, AC is the accepted abbreviation.

Comment: The IEEE standards lists lower case as a correct abbreviation.  But I guess others know better.  I hate nitpicking editting.